# How to integrate a function on the area of an ellipse

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

We have a function:
$$\iint_T \sin{(9x^2 + 4y^2  )}dxdy$$, where $T = \{(x,y)| 9x^2 + 4y^2 < 1\}$

However I tried it with polar coordinates and got nowhere. What should I use to be able to start this exercise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First put $x'=3x$ and $y'=2y$. Now you are on a disk and you can use polar coordinates. Note that the integral of $r \sin(r^2)$ can be computed by setting $s = r^2$.

Cheers!